# Duplicating forms with logic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have created a dynamic form field that I add and remove through a callback function on buttons `DelBtn()` to remove item and `AddBtn()` to add item

Each of this form fields have a `value` input

I also have a `totalval` field. I expect the sum of values in all the `value` field not to exceed the `totalval`. If it does we display an a error message and if the value equals we make the `reason` form field appear.

**Example:**

If I have `totalValue = 100` . Now lets say I have my first form field `value = 90`.

Then I duplicate the form and in the next field set `value = 10` then the `reason` field should appear because `90 + 10 = 100`.
**As the `totalValue` has been reached the `reason` form field should appear and the add button should be disabled**.

If in the second attempt if the user tries to enter a value more than 10 then an error message should be shown.

Below is my current code

In my TS File I have

```typescript
  ischecks: boolean = true;
  formsArray = [""];
  count: number = 0;
  totalval: number = 100;

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  constructor() {}

  clickCount(): void {
    this.count++;
  }

  DelBtn = delIndex => this.formsArray.splice(delIndex, 1);
  AddBtn = () => this.formsArray.push("");
```

HTML

```html
<h2> Form</h2>

<pre style="font-weight: bolder;font-family:verdana;margin-left: 35px;">Total Value:{{totalval}}       </pre>
<div *ngFor="let i of formsArray; let a = index">

    <div>
        <form>
            <table>
                <div>
                    <label for="fname">Value:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ><br>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
        style="border-radius:40px;margin-left: 50px" (click)="DelBtn(a)" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </div>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf=ischecks style="margin-left:35%">
    <label for="fname">Reason:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ><br>
</div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
            style="border-radius:40px;margin-left: 50px;margin-bottom: 30%;" (click)="AddBtn()"  ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Add</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3pbdwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Note: If you do not understand the question feel free to ask me in comments adn I am working in angular(typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be difficult to achieve with basic `Javascript`. Below approach uses `ReactiveForm` approach

**We Follow the below steps**

- Add the `ReactiveFormsModule` to the `imports` array of the module

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports:[ ReactiveFormsModule, ... ],
```

- Inject the `FormBuilder` class

```typescript
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

- Define the form

```typescript
myForm = this.fb.group({
  totalVal: [100],
  formsArray: this.fb.array([this.fb.control("", { validators: [Validators.required] })]),
  reason: ["", [Validators.required]]
}, { validators: [sumMatches] });
```

We have added a cusom validator `sumMatches`. We will use this to check whether the sum of the total value has been matched

```typescript
function sumMatches(control): ValidationErrors | undefined {
  const totalVal = Number(control.get("totalVal").value);
  const formsArrayTotal = control
    .get("formsArray")
    .value.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
  if (formsArrayTotal !== totalVal) {
    return {
      sumMismatch: true
    };
  }
  return;
}
```

- Next we define helper `getter` functions to extract properties from the `formGroup`

```typescript
  get sumMismatch(): boolean {
    return this.myForm.hasError('sumMismatch')
  }
  get arrayFullyFilled() {
    return !this.formsArray.controls.some(item => item.errors)
  }
  get formsArray() {
    return this.myForm.get("formsArray") as FormArray;
  }
  get totalVal() {
    return this.myForm.get("totalVal") as FormControl;
  }
```

- We also need to amend the functions to add and remove items from the formArray

```typescript
  DelBtn = delIndex => this.formsArray.controls.splice(delIndex, 1);
  AddBtn = () => this.formsArray.push(this.fb.control(""));
```

- Finally we can implement the `formGroup` in the html

```html
<h2> Form</h2>

<span class='totalVal'>Total Value:{{ totalVal.value }}</span>

<form [formGroup]='myForm'>
    <ng-container formArrayName='formsArray'>
        <table *ngFor="let item of formsArray.controls; let i = index">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <label [attr.for]="'fname' + i">Value:</label><br>
                        <input type="number" [formControlName]="i" type="text" [id]="'fname' + i" name="fname" ><br>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
        s (click)="DelBtn(i)" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Delete</button></td>
            <tr>

        </table>
    </ng-container>
    <div *ngIf='!sumMismatch && arrayFullyFilled'>
        <label for="fname">Reason:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ><br>
</div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
       (click)="AddBtn()"  ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Add</button>
        <br>
  <span class="error" *ngIf="sumMismatch && myForm.touched">Total Value Mismatch</span>
</form>
```

I have extracted css to own file

```css
.totalVal {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: verdana;
}
.btn-outline-success {
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

[See this Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yyffwf)

### Edit 1 - How Does the validator work?

To understand this we look at how we build our form group. We defined a structure that produces a value in the form

```json
  {
    totalVal: 100,
    formsArray: [''],
    reason: ''
  }
```

By defining our form group as `this.fb.group({ ... }, {validators: [ sumMatches ] }` the form group with the above value will be passed to the sumMatches function

In the `sumMatches` we will have a something like a `formGroup` with the value

```json
  {
    totalVal: 100,
    formsArray: ['50', '20', '10'],
    reason: ''
  }
```

In the above we simply extract the 100 from the `formGroup` using `control.get('totalVal').value` same to `formArray`. Since `formArray` value will be an array then we can use `reduce` function to sum this.. We finally compare this and return null if they match and an `Object` if they do not match.

With the above approach, angular reactive forms will update the value of the form `valid` status based on what is provided by the user. We can hence leverage this `valid` status to update the `UI`

**arrayFullyFilled()**

```typescript
get arrayFullyFilled() { 
  return !this.formsArray.controls.some(item => item.errors) 
}
```

The above code tries to find if the user has filled **ALL** the inputs in the array. In our array we get all the controls, check if some of them have errors and if any has error return false otherwise return true. This is made possible considering that in my `formGroup` I had made the `formControls` as `required` using `Validators.required` validation

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. can you please explain the code elaborately?

Comment: Which part would you like clarification on?

Comment: Can you explain me the validators required section. I understand the functionality but can u explain how you have looped the formbuilder within itself?

Comment: get arrayFullyFilled() {
    return !this.formsArray.controls.some(item => item.errors)
  }        I also dont understand this line clearly?